# Is there any way to get vim to auto wrap python strings at 79 chars?

Tags: python, vim, string, word-wrap

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302364/python-pep8-printing-wrapped-strings-without-indent/1302381#1302381) about wrapping strings using parens extremely useful, but is there a way in Vim to make this happen automatically?  I want to be within a string, typing away, and have Vim just put parens around my string and wrap it as necessary.  For me, this would be a *gigantic* time saver as I spend so much time just wrapping long strings manually.  Thanks in advance.

Example:

1. I type the following text:

   ```
   mylongervarname = "my really long string here so please wrap and quote
   automatically"
   ```
2. Vim automatically does this when I hit column 80 with the string:

   ```
   mylongervarname = ("my really long string here so please wrap and "
                      "quote automatically")
   ```

Comment: If this is within docstrings, you can always use vim's gq to wrap the text. If it's inline..  why do you have so much long inline text?

Comment: It just occurs when something like help_text for a member needs to be added.  It does not happen that often, but when it does it is such a pain that I'm looking for any way to avoid it.

Comment: Also, it happens a lot just because of the default tab setup, where a string will be automatically indentented to the end of a long line.  E.g. self.fields['description'].help_text = "some text here that is already very far in."

Comment: Glad you liked my answer. I don't know the answer to this one, but it's something I'd probably use as well.  I will say that if you have a bunch of long strings, it might make sense to just triple quote them and/or include them in an external file.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but will setting "set textwidth=80" in .vimrc somewhat work for you?

Answer (score 12):

More a direction than a solution.

Use `'formatexpr'` or `'formatprg'`.  When a line exceeds `'textwidth'` and passes the criteria set by the `'formatoptions'` these are used (if set) to break the line.  The only real difference is that `'formatexpr'` is a vimscript expression, while `'formatprg'` filters the line through an exterior program.

So if you know of a formatter that can do this transformation to lines of python code, or are willing to write one, this will give you a hook to have it executed.  And since vim supports python (see `:help python`) you can even write your python formatter in python.

Comment: I tried writing a formatexpr, but I had trouble even getting it to run.  I've searched and searched for examples or docs about writing one of these, but have consistently found barely anything.

Comment: here's an example http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg08443.html (see `autofmt.zip:autofmt/autoload/autofmt/compat.vim`)