# Vim: wrap text (ie, "gq") without breaking strings?

Tags: vim

I often use `gq` to wrap code… But it isn't very smart when it comes to strings. For example, wrapping:

```
foo = bar("a b c d e f")
```

Might result in:

```
foo = bar("a b c
          d e f")
```

Which, obviously, isn't nearly as useful as:

```
foo = bar("a b c " +
          "d e f")
```

would be.

Is there any way to wrap text which takes this into account?

Comment: I'd love to see a solution for this. I'm certain it would require a vim script though, which I have no knowledge of...

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314174/is-there-any-way-to-get-vim-to-auto-wrap-python-strings-at-79-chars.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to make gq do this out of the box, but the solution I have used is to write a custom function and map, in my case gqc, to it.

Something akin to [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=886)