# Auto wrap long lines in VIM

Tags: vim, word-wrap

When I edit a haskell file in Vim, my editor automatically wraps comments that go past 80 characters to the next line. I'd like Vim to use the same behavior for python files (and text files), but I can't find the setting that does this anywhere, in my `~/.vim/syntax` folder or `vimrc`.

Here are relevant lines of my .vimrc:

```
set wrap
set textwidth=80
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting `textwidth` will put your maximum line length.  This would put a new line at that character point (white space could play with an exact 80 a bit though).  (This effects the actual formatting of your file).

`wrap` is indeed what you want for your splitting/wrapping though.

Make sure your .vimrc is in your home directory.

Comment: This question on stackoverflow talks about some python wrapping stuff as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314174/is-there-any-way-to-get-vim-to-auto-wrap-python-strings-at-79-chars

Comment: Thanks - I think adding "c" to my `formatoptions` helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I uses the following script in my vimrc to wrap .txt file automatically. This may give you some hints.

```
if has('autocmd')
  au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt set wm=2 tw=80
endif
```

Comment: If `textwidth != 0` then `wordmargin` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

If a line is already longer than textwidth when insert mode is started, the line may not be wrapped even if text is added to the line. A long line is not wrapped when text is added if [formatoptions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'formatoptions') contains "l". If needed, "l" can be removed like so:

```
:set fo-=l
```

You can check the value of your formatoptions via:

```
:set fo?
```

You can learn the meaning of those letters [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table) or via:

```
:he fo-table
```