# how to configure vim to smartly wrap python strings?

Tags: python, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to get vim to auto wrap python strings at 79 chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314174/is-there-any-way-to-get-vim-to-auto-wrap-python-strings-at-79-chars)

Currently, my vim auto wraps code lines at 80th col. This is a nice feature but it causes SyntaxError when it comes to strings - breaking a string into multiple lines.

Example:

```
self.assertEqual(resp.context['poll'].question, 'Are you learning about
    testing about testing in Django?')
```

Is there a way to configure vim to smartly do like the following when it comes to wrapping strings?

```
self.assertEqual(resp.context['poll'].question, 'Are you learning about '
    'testing about testing in Django?')
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space in there somewhere, "learning abouttesting about testing" ...

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves - Thx for pointing out the possible duplicate. I took a look at the question but I don't think mine is a duplicate of it. Not to mention, the question has remained unanswered for over two years.

Comment: @ldigas - oops, you're right. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I am by no means an expert in programming, but I think it's very bad practice to break lines in code. Why don't you use break indent patch https://retracile.net/attachment/blog/2009/11/20/12.00/vim-7.2-breakindent.patch

Comment: @ahmoo I don't know why you think it isn't a duplicate. The only real difference is that the other question also mentions adding surrounding parens. Also, I'm not sure if the lack of an answer to the other question would actually be relevant, but in any case the other question *does* have answers. Despite the fact that it wasn't accepted, rampion's answer is applicable to your situation: use 'formatexpr' or 'formatprg'. Not exactly "turn-key", but it is the right answer.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves - After careful going through the other SO post careful, I think you are right. I got only part of it the first time I skimmed through. Thanks.

Comment: @puk The convention and standard `PEP 8` suggests that wrapping at char 79, this will make code readable in the low-end computers and it also enables to split scree for 2 different files in current computers. Also, if you don't wrap your code at all, it may go horizontally to the void which you might have to use horizontal scrolling even if you have 1 file open in a today's computer.